# Does Seventh Generation fabric softener fray tzitzit?

Tags: tzitzis, tallit-katan, cleaning

Has anyone had experience cleaning tzitzit strings with [Seventh Generation](https://www.seventhgeneration.com) fabric softener? Does it damage them or is it safe?

When I clean my begadim, I let soap get on the strings, but since I have techeilet on my arba' kanfot, I'm very careful to keep away anything that might damage the tzitzit, due to their cost.

Comment: On a side note, Machon Ptil Tekhelet has greatly lowered their price over the years (although they are still expensive).

Comment: @ezra, I'm aware. My first set of Tosafot strings ended up being over $100, not it's ~$70 (I use thick tzitzit on all of my begadim, even though I tuck in my tallis koton)

Comment: For my own info / curiosity ... can you provide a link regarding the type of tziztzit that you bought - or something similar? I'm an ignoramus in this area.

Comment: @DanF, two sets of thick Raavad 7 from http://tzitzit.tallit-shop.com/ptil-tekhelet-tzitzit-strings/ to make one set of Tosafot tzitzit

Comment: @DanF - What's particularly interesting about the Tosafot tzitzit tying method is that it requires that on each tassel 4 techelet strings hang down on the completed tzitzit. Because of this, the method requires 2 sets of techelet strings to make, unlike other methods.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - Since Tosafot tzitzit require 2 sets of techelet strings, I'm not surprised. But did you see that instead of $70 for thick strings, it's now $50 on Ptil Tekhelet's website as well as Ben's? (BTW, I was the one who told Ben about the price drop. We were both shocked.)